# Change input type='time' in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this input field, where the user has to enter their startime, and then I was wondering if it was possible to change the marked dropdown time to another? The dropdown starts at UTC+2 but I want it to start at UTC+0 so instead of `09:59` it should start at `07:59`.

[image: utc2]

Would it be possible to use this Javascript timestamp to update the input time?

```js
setInterval(time, 1000);
function time() {
    var span = document.getElementById('span');
    var d = new Date().toUTCString().split(' ')[4];
    span.textContent = "Current UTC+0 time: " + d;
}
```

```html
<input class='form-control w-100' style='width:auto;' type='time' id='mt_start' name='mt_start' required>

<div class='d-flex justify-content-end fixed-top mt-5 mr-1' style='z-index: -1;'>
  <h3><span class='badge badge-secondary' id='span'>Current UTC+0 time: </span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: What bit exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @Liam In stuck at making the dropdown start at UTC+0, I don't want it to start at UTC+2

Comment: It always starts on your current local time, you can give it a computed value change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of the time input, like so:

```html
<input type="time" value="19:59">
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the input directly with `document.querySelector('#mt_start').value`. Use the time string that you save in the variable `d`:

```js
document.querySelector('#mt_start').value = new Date().toUTCString().split(' ')[4];
```

```html
<input type='time' id='mt_start'>
```